# zc.buildout: Script Recipe With Access to Buildout Configuration

Tags: buildout

I want to write a script in a zc.buildout recipe, but the script needs to have access to buildout.cfg.

I know how to create a buildout recipe (which has access to its configuration) and how to create a buildout script, but I don't know how the script could read the config.

- Is there a way that the script receive the configuration from buildout.cfg?
- Or should it open the file by itself and parse the config?
- In the last case, what is the best way to get the path? what's the best way to parse it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by *script* here? A `bin/script` command generated by a recipe, or a script run as part of a recipe *install* or *update* call?

Comment: If the first, this sounds very much like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem); can you tell us more about what you are trying to do?

Comment: Add a bin/script. The idea is to ease the deployment with a command. At certain point the user will type bin/deploy and the script will visit certain src/ folders and execute git commands. But I want to be able to configure which folders, so I though that I could put the config in the same buildout section that creates the script.

Comment: You could use a template (`collective.recipe.template`), you can pull in any buildout value you'd like with those. You can also create a console script in a `setup.py` script, and give it `initialization` code in a `zc.recipe.egg` part.